# Nginx daemon is failing to resatrt/stop/start

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, passenger

I have a typical problem.

I was working on server configuration for rails using nginx and passenger.
how ever i have installed the nginx passenger module.

then i configured correctly the nginx at /opt/nginx/conf directory.

Then when i try to restart/strat/reload/stop it says:
Restarting nginx: /etc/init.d/nginx: line 42: start-stop-daemon: command not found.

My restart config is at /etc/init.d/nginx 
and there i have

```
restart|force-reload)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \
            /opt/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON
    sleep 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \
            /opt/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
```

i am working on centos.
please help me i cant figured it out why its happening.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing where line 42 is, I think your problem is that you're actually passing the `--exec $DAEMON` argument along with the `--stop` argument. In all init scripts I've written so far I used `start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} --name ${NAME}` where `${NAME}` only contains the name of the executable (in our case `nginx`). No clue if this is your problem, no clue if this is the problem in line 42. The error message sounds like it can't find `start-stop-daemon` at all (which is very unlikely).

Comment: thanks @Fleshgrinder.I am new to server site management so it seems tough to understand.I will work on your suggestion.